# Asp.Net weird name?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I know with ASP.Net 4.0 you can have ClientIDMode to static to have clean ID.

Is there something to have "name" the same way?

Example :

```
<input type="text" name="_wizard$ctl00$CaptionName" id="captionName">
```

Comment: Why? What are you doing with the `name`?

Comment: I parse the Request.Form. Trying to build a dynamic wizard and each step are dynamic so I do not use the ViewState because the step is not build back when hitting "Next".

Comment: Then you shouldn't be using server-side controls at all.

Comment: Well, the usercontrol use some server side stuff so yeah we will use them. The question is not an alternative but a solution to the problem.

Comment: You can still get the current posted values with ViewState turned off.  Viewstate only determines what the values were when they were sent to the view.

Comment: Even by disabling the ViewState the name generated contain $_$...

Comment: it still generates that kind of name, my point is that you don't need to look in the request tree to get it.  unless you mean you're posting to a different page, in which case I agree with SLaks, don't use server side controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could output a key/pair javascript collection with the list of controls you're looking to operate on client-side. Control.ClientID and ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript are your friends.